# cannot run maven sure fire (POJO) test

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

strangely, this was working few weeks ago and my changes messed up working tree.
I feel like I am asking obvious question (that was answered many times on this site), but going no where after spending several hours on late friday and ran out of ideas.

1. All my test files are in folder `src\test\java`
2. Filenames are `*Test.java`
3. Method names are `test*`
4. methods are non-static

I do `mvn clean test -X -Dtest=*Dumb* -DfailIfNoTests=false` and notice that class files are created (yes I tried `mvn clean test -X` and settled with above to keep it simple).

Below is classpath it prints (not sure how it got junit*.jar; my pom doesnt have junit)

```
[DEBUG] test(compact) classpath:  test-classes  classes  classes  harmonia-timeseries-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  gwt-servlet-2.6.1.jar  gwtquery-1.3.3.jar  junit-4.11.jar  hamcrest-core-1.3.jar  gxt-3.1.0.jar  validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar  gxt-theme-neptune-3.1.0.jar  gxt-chart-3.1.0.jar  httpclient-4.3.3.jar  httpcore-4.3.2.jar  commons-codec-1.6.jar  json-20140107.jar  gwt-elemental-2.6.1.jar  gwt-user-2.6.1.jar  json-simple-1.1.jar  kafka_2.10-0.8.1.jar  metrics-annotation-2.2.0.jar  metrics-core-2.2.0.jar  snappy-java-1.0.5.jar  zookeeper-3.3.4.jar  jline-0.9.94.jar  jopt-simple-3.2.jar  scala-library-2.10.1.jar  zkclient-0.3.jar  drools-core-5.5.0.Final.jar  mvel2-2.1.3.Final.jar  knowledge-api-5.5.0.Final.jar  knowledge-internal-api-5.5.0.Final.jar  drools-compiler-5.5.0.Final.jar  antlr-runtime-3.3.jar  antlr-3.3.jar  stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar  antlr-2.7.7.jar  ecj-3.5.1.jar  xstream-1.4.1.jar  xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar  xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar  commons-email-1.3.2.jar  mail-1.4.5.jar  activation-1.1.1.jar  joda-time-2.3.jar  guava-17.0.jar  jcabi-xml-0.8.1.jar  jcabi-immutable-1.1.jar  commons-collections-3.2.1.jar  commons-jxpath-1.3.jar  commons-beanutils-1.9.1.jar  commons-logging-1.1.1.jar  commons-configuration-1.10.jar  commons-lang-2.6.jar  jsoup-1.7.3.jar  sigar-1.6.4.129.jar  jcabi-aspects-0.12.jar  jcabi-log-0.7.jar  hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar  jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar  validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar  aspectjrt-1.6.12.jar  slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar  slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar  log4j-1.2.17.jar  lombok-1.12.4.jar
```

[DEBUG] provider(compact) classpath:  surefire-junit4-2.17.jar  surefire-api-2.17.jar

Below is the configuration it prints

```
       [DEBUG]   (s) reportFormat = brief
        [DEBUG]   (s) reportsDirectory =         
       C:\**\target\surefire-reports
         [DEBUG]   (f) reuseForks = true
      [DEBUG]   (s) runOrder = filesystem
      [DEBUG]   (s) skip = false
      [DEBUG]   (s) skipTests = false
      [DEBUG]   (s) test = *Dumb*
      [DEBUG]   (s) testClassesDirectory =                   
       C:\*\target\test-classes
       [DEBUG]   (s) testFailureIgnore = false
         [DEBUG]   (s) testNGArtifactName = org.testng:testng
     [DEBUG]   (s) testSourceDirectory =           
     C:\*\src\test\java
    [DEBUG]   (s) threadCountClasses = 0
      [DEBUG]   (s) threadCountMethods = 0
        [DEBUG]   (s) threadCountSuites = 0
     [DEBUG]   (s) trimStackTrace = true
        [DEBUG]   (s) useFile = true
      [DEBUG]   (s) useManifestOnlyJar = true
        [DEBUG]   (s) useSystemClassLoader = true
       [DEBUG]   (s) useUnlimitedThreads = false
       [DEBUG]   (s) workingDirectory = C:\*\ashore
```

Sadly, I get the following output

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Below is the plugin from effective pom

```
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-test</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <property>
            <name>printSummary</name>
            <value>true</value>
          </property>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>printSummary</name>
        <value>true</value>
      </property>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
```

I know I am asking trivial question; but I cant figure out; thanks folks.

**EDIT**

5: Ensure other test frameworks (testng/junit) are not getting on your way to run POJO tests

Based on Alexy's answer: added following

```
      <configuration>
              <junitArtifactName>none:none</junitArtifactName>
             <testNGArtifactName>none:none</testNGArtifactName> 
        </configuration>
```

Comment: Does it run any tests if you don't specify -Dtest=*Dumb*?

Comment: Please show your full pom and not the effective pom furthermore added one of your unit tests here.

Comment: @Alex: It wont run any tests with or without arguments

Comment: @khmarbaise: note these are working test cases few weeks back. I added few dependencies (from other internal projects) in the pom files. Do you see any reason why that may be causing this problem?

Comment: If you don't answer the question we couldn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your project has only JUnit 4 tests, it could be that `surefire` is looking for TestNG tests instead because `testng` is now in the project class path.

You can try to identify the `testng` dependency running `mvm dependency:tree` and then exclude it.

You can also try disable TestNG support in the `surefire` plugin configuration:

```
        <configuration> 
            <testNGArtifactName>none:none</testNGArtifactName>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: surefire plugin automatically determines that.

Comment: @Alexey: it is working-thanks a lot. One of the internal dependencies is bringing in junit and adding none:none did the trick